# nodejs tools for automated authoring

Tags: javascript, node.js

Nodejs is a powerfull tool, but makes my life hard, because I have to create a server by hand, from scratch.

I have no experience with writing code to manipulate server connections and implementing server security. I am experienced with setting a server (using an installer) and then creating a database, making queries, uploading files, authoring php,html5,js,css etc. But, little to zero experience with servers, this is why nodejs is a black box to me.

Are there any tools (or modules, or apps) out there that automate the process of enabling security, managing connections (taking care of the basics), using an UI? Tools that set up a strong bedrock and at the same time let me freely develop and add to nodejs my own js functions (for websockets, for example).

This will speed up my workflow and ensure a quality nodejs server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not a UI - but `express` is powerful middleware for node that makes life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use yeoman http://yeoman.io/ tamplates to preconfig you server

Comment: To add on here, a couple popular generators are [generator-express](https://github.com/petecoop/generator-express) which creates an [Express](http://expressjs.com/) based Node app.  If you'd like to use [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) on top, then [generator-angular-fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) adds to that Express concept by adding Angular on top.  These might be good starting points for apps.

Answer (score -1):

Well if you gived yourself a chance to study the Node.js language you'll notice that Node.js already does most of the magic work for you. All Node.js really needs is on which port do you want your server to listen on. In other technologies, it's pretty common to have the "port" stuff in configuration files. It's only a few lines of Node.js code to specify on which port you want your server to start on.

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');

}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

I mean ... what is there to automate ?

After which you can use express.js framework to structure your web project in a MVC fashion. Like what other posters say.

In express.js the "routes" are kind of like controller actions... etc.